# Set up one time postgres remote server connection through terminal

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, terminal

I have remote postgres server link with all needed parameters.

Every day i have to connect to remote server by pasting this ->

```
psql -h <IP_Address> -p <port_no> -d <database_name> -U <DB_username> -W
```

Can I somehow avoid using this, like connection stays there the way it is in pgadmin

Comment: You can create an alias in your .bashrc file, something like `alias db='psql -h <IP_Address> -p <port_no> -d <database_name> -U <DB_username> -W'`. Then you only type `db` in your terminal

Comment: Use a [psqlrc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.20.10) file to avoid having to enter the password. Or setup [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) so `psql` defaults to them. Or setup a [service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html)  to avoid having to enter connection details.